# How to define index method in elasticsearch in yii2?

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2-advanced-app

I am using filters in Elasticsearch in yii2, I  want to have an exact match to a field for example item_name="tshirt", so I want to define an index for this field as 'not_analyzed', how do I define index in yii2-elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

You can override index() method in your search model.